# How to deal with data writing WriteProcessRejectException warning in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When Apache IoTDB is inserting new data, the backstage reported this following warning, but the writing process did not stop. Should I do anything about this warning and what may be the reason for this warning?

```
WARN o.a.i.d.u.ErrorhandlingUtils:146 - Exception occurred while processing non-query. org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.BatchProcessException: Batchfailed: \[TSStatus(code:413, message: org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.StorageEngineException: org.apache.iotdb.db.exception.WriteProcessRejectException: System rejected over 10011ms)\]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D9f4.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code and errors. It's barely readable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a rejection warning, and when this happens, it means that the speed of Apache IoTDB flushing the disk cannot keep up with the speed of writing data, so the system will automatically use RejectException to block writing. You can try to pause the disk backup process for a while and see if this warning disappears.